# What is the meaning of " it goes on you "?

Tags: meaning

Someone told me that Americans use "it goes on you" instead of "it suits you."  But I couldn't find the answer on internet.  Is it really common to use it or not?

Comment: As an American, I've never heard this usage.  Are you sure that the phrase isn't "it grows on you", used to refer to something that seems unpleasant at first but becomes more appealing with increased exposure?

Comment: Sb told you wrong. You can say *That tie **goes with** your shirt*, but it's not idiomatic to use ***go*** on its own in the the same way as *That dress suits you* (or more dated/formal *It **becomes** you*).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on the false premise that the cited usage has any currency among native speakers.

Comment: @DougWarren Yes I'm sure . So its wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are not because we English learners do not have any other source to reach some of our answers. if you are doing that I'm so sorry for whole this group

Comment: There's ["**It's you!**"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/it-s-you) that's similar in meaning and structure to both the expressions you mention.

Comment: @Yazdan: Not so. Even here on Stack Exchange you English learners have [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), which was *specifically created* for your needs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you . So I'm not posting any questions in this forum anymore.

Comment: @Yazdan: I look forward to answering your future questions on ELL. But note that *this particular question* might be considered Off Topic there for the same reason I've given here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, my god. So how shall I solve my English questions ???

Comment: *You* probably won't solve your English questions. But there are plenty of users over on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) who might solve them *for* you.